# Bulk insert affecting 0 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I'm having trouble bulk importing a .csv file. This is the first time I've tried this and I'm not sure why it is not importing data how I'd like. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
CREATE TABLE DM_Stage.dbo.rate_1
        (
            [position]                              varchar(200) NULL
            ,[const]                                varchar(200) NULL
            ,[created]                              varchar(200) NULL
            ,[modified]                             varchar(200) NULL
            ,[description]                          varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Title]                                varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Title Type]                           varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Directors]                            varchar(200) NULL
            ,[You Rated]                            varchar(200) NULL
            ,[IMDb Rating]                          varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Runtime (mins)]                       varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Year]                                 varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Genres]                               varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Num. Votes]                           varchar(200) NULL
            ,[Release Date (month/day/year)]        varchar(200) NULL
            ,[URL]                                  varchar(200) NULL
        )



    BULK INSERT [DM_Stage].dbo.[rate_1] FROM
    "C:\Users\me\Downloads\Personal\IMDb Ratings\User Ratings\rating1.csv"
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '"',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW=2
    )
```

Thank you!

Comment: should the fieldterminator be `,` instead of `"` as it is a `csv` file?

Comment: @vkp I tried that as well but it doesn't change the row count.

Comment: could you please show how the data in the csv file looks like? atleast the first few rows?

Comment: how about sharing the error?  without that, we can only guess what is wrong.